# Best way to get the custom object type of a WhatId in a Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, tasks, describesobject, whatid

I'm working on a Task record-triggered flow and I need to evaluate the WhatId to see what the object type is. As I see it's not directly available. I'm wondering if what the best solution would be. I know if could leverage the prefix, but not sure if there is an easier way. Right now the object has not yet been deployed, so the prefixes are different among Sandboxes.

Comment: Have you tried pulling `What.Type`? It works in SOQL but not sure about flow.

Comment: I tried that, but with no luck. The only thing I can think of is creating an Apex Action and call from the Flow.

Comment: Not a bad way to go.